# How can I direct output from a program to fill a form on a webpage?

Tags: linux, forms, input, barcode

My 1D barcode scanner appears as an input device in Linux allowing me to fill a web page form with barcode scans exactly as if I was manually typing the input.  I need to replicate this 'scan--put data into web form' behaviour using a 2D barcodes read from a webcam and extracted with the command line utility.
The utility I'm using (zbarcam), prints the detected code to stdout whenever a barcode is detected---very nice!
I need somehow to redirect that stdout stream to the current web page in my browser so I can fill in a text box with the data.
This seems like a simple redirection problem but I can't figure out how to make it work.  Perhaps there is a way to make a utility act as a 'virtual' input device?

Comment: please specify what kind of server side technology are you using: php, java, etc

Comment: The page is produced using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go this way.

First send the output of your app to a temp location, so that file will get automatically updated everytime you read a new barcode.

```
zbarcam <params> > /tmp/barcodeoutput
```

Then you would create an script like this one that will automatically using ajax and jquery refresh its contents.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jquery ajax</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#content").load("feed.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#content").load('feed.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 2000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <pre id="content">

    </pre>

</body>
</html>
```

And the last file would be the php file that index.php will call using ajax.

feed.php

```
<?php
readfile('/tmp/barcodeoutput');


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "crikey"!

*zbarcam -raw /dev/video0 | crikey -i*

First, you have to download and compile "crikey", like this:

sudo apt-get install libx11-dev x11proto-xext-dev libxt-dev libxtst-dev

wget http://www.shallowsky.com/software/crikey/crikey-0.8.3.tar.gz

tar -xzf crikey-0.8.3.tar.gz

cd crikey-0.8.3

make

sudo cp crikey /usr/local/bin

Now, you got everything ready to work, capture and decode your barcode, exactly where you put the cursor.... a Gedit window, Google input box, any app...

Just type **zbarcam --raw /dev/video0 | crikey -i**

If the command above does NOT work, try..
**zbarcam --raw /dev/video1 | crikey -i**

If you got a webcam that only works with V4L1, try the following command.
**LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so zbarcam --raw /dev/video1 | crikey -i**

or
**LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so zbarcam --raw /dev/video0 |crikey -i**

Here you got a videoclip showing how I capture any barcode and get the result in anywhere...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPe_9bhPtT4

Enjoy! Any comment or doubt, send me an email at fmft71 at yahoo dot es

Regards

MrFMFT71

Answer (score 0):

a better way is sending that output to a script (or a console program), which does a POST request to the web form. Perl is a good candidate for this. It is definitely harder (if you are not familiar with writing a program that does POST request), but I think it's a better way to do it.

Comment: I agree this is a good technique and can certainly do a POST.  The really nice part about the original barcode scanner is it's ability to enter data into the *current* page.  E.g Joe User has logged into a web app, navigated to a particular page and now enters data using a barcode scanner.  I think the POST method would have to have my current users session information as well as figuring out which page they were using.

Answer (score 0):

I may help with the second part of your question: getting your program to upload data to your server or generate a web page. You need to be familiar with HTML forms (and how they are submitted with GET and POST).

### Upload data directly to your server

Use libCURL in C or urllib in Python to perform a form submission. Your C or python program can simulate the action of a guy who enters values into a form and clicks submit. You just need to see the source of your web page and devise your program accordingly.

**For example**: response=urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8983?q=well&fl=id&wt=python') in python is an example of a GET request. **For example**, When you search *hp laptop* in google, it requests for the page *http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=hp+laptop&fp=1*

### Current web page-- and awful hack

That seems an **awful** approach, its not at all robust. But it may enter all values in your form for you. You may call a

```
system("browser-command url+*javascript*")
```

from a C program. This simulates opening a browser in command line. Chromium takes care to open the URL in a new tab. You will need to make some inline javascript code to set the values of your form.

For inline javascript code http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptvoid.php

For learning Document Object Model (manipulating elements in your page): http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ex_dom.asp